Declaration and implementation of the copy constructor in a template class, C++
In a class template, I declare the copy constructor and implement it outside of the class in the following way:
template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
MyClass(const MyClass<T> & other);
}

template<typename T>
MyClass<T>::MyClass(const MyClass<T> & other)
{
// Implementation
}

But I saw another kind of declaration and implementation, where there is no <T> after MyClass in the parameter list:
template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
MyClass(const MyClass & other);
}

template<typename T>
MyClass<T>::MyClass(const MyClass & other)
{
// Implementation
}

Which one is correct and what is the difference between these two kinds of declaration?
I try both in Visual Studio and both work. It makes me feel that they are equivalent but I am not sure about that.

It's just a shorthand permitted by the standard.  Within certain templated declarations (a definition is formally just a type of declaration), it is permitted to remove the template parameter.

The search term for further research is injected class name

@Peter, thank you for your response! So they are the same thing? Whatever is inside the template parameter list when an object is instantiated, e.g. MyClass<int> myClass, the member function will be automatically interpreted as MyClass(const MyClass<int>& other), is it correct?

@William - Yes, that is correct. Inside the class (or member function) the class name represents the current MyClass<T>, with whatever T is.
